# PostgreSQL – How to know specific name or OID of a function/procedure that was just created?

Tags: database, postgresql, stored-procedures, objectid

If a `CREATE FUNCTION/PROCEDURE` is executed, is there any way to get the oid or the specific name of the object that was just created?

It seems the only way is to look tediously look at the parameter lists for each function/procedure as listed in the system catalogs or information_schema, and compare until you find an exact match?

Comment: [Event trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/event-triggers.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [system object identifier types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html) for this:

> The OID alias types have no operations of their own except for specialized input and output routines. These routines are able to accept and display symbolic names for system objects, rather than the raw numeric value that type oid would use. The alias types allow simplified lookup of OID values for objects. […] The […] input converter handles the table lookup according to the schema path setting, and so it does the “right thing” automatically.

In particular, to get the the oids of functions or procedures, you'd use `regprocedure`, e.g.

```
SELECT 'public.test()'::regprocedure::oid;
SELECT 'public.test(int, int)'::regprocedure::oid;
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/vOf6FMYg))</sup>

Comment: I had not considered that tacking on the arguments to the name in that cast was allowed. That'll do. Thanks!

Comment: @seth `regproc` (instead of `regprocedure`) doesn't use argument types, but does not work when the function is overloaded (ie. different functions with the same name but different signature).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the OID of `my_func()` function with `regproc` type, `regprocedure` type, `to_regproc()` or `to_regprocedure()` and `oid` type as shown below:

```sql
SELECT 'public.my_func'::regproc::oid;
```

Or:

```sql
SELECT 'public.my_func(INTEGER, INTEGER)'::regprocedure::oid;
```

Or:

```sql
SELECT to_regproc('my_func')::oid;
```

Or:

```sql
SELECT to_regprocedure('public.my_func(INTEGER, INTEGER)')::oid;
```

*Memos:

- You can also use these ways above with a procedure.